# How to compare values from struct and array in ColdFusion?

Tags: arrays, csv, coldfusion, structure

I have situation where I have to compare values from structure and array. My structure is created and populated with values from query. Array is created and populated with values from .csv file. Now I need to loop through each of them, compare specific values and then if they match move those values in the list. I will have to use that list later to update/insert records in two different tables. Here is my code for structure:

```
<cfquery name="getRecords" datasource="test">
    Select s.ID, f.OLDID, s.USER_NUMBER, s.STATUS, f.DINING
    From USERS s
    Left Outer Join FIELDS f
    ON s.ID = f.OLDID
</cfquery>  

<cfset myStruct = StructNew()>

<cfloop query="getRecords">
    <cfset myStruct[USER_NUMBER] = {id1=ID,id2=OLDID,st=STATUS,din=DINING}>
</cfloop>
```

Here is my code that creates array from .csv file:

```
<cffile action="read" file="#whfile#" variable="myfile">
<cfset myarray = ListToArray(myfile, chr(13))>
<cfset cnt = ArrayLen(myarray)>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to=#(cnt)# step="1">
    <cfset myrow = #replace(myarray[i],chr(10),'')#>
    <cfset myrow = ListToArray(myrow,",",true)>
    //Here I can loop through array and grab value from specific column
</cfloop>
```

I never done comparing from two different arrays or structures before. What is the best way to compare values from these two lists. For example I would have to compare USER_NUMBER from my struct and myrow[1] that represent column 1 which holds USER_NUMBER populated from .csv file. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Read your csv file with a cfhttp tag that has a name attribute.  That will produce a query object.  Use query of queries to compare that data to the your getRecords query.

Comment: @DanBracuk can you provide any example for that? I did not work with something like that before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an example here ==> https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html