# Best way to compare values from DB and CSV file?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, csv, coldfusion, cfloop

I'm working on project where I have to read values from data base and compare them with values from .csv file. After I run my cfquery I get about 14k records returned. My .csv file has about the same number of records. I'm looking for the best and the most efficient way to compare these records and store them in some structure/array that I will be able to use later to update records that are different. I'm using SQL for update of these records. One note before I showed you my example, I'm not able to use temporary table in this project what makes everything more complex. Here is my example of how I pull the values from DB and compare them with records from .csv file:

```
<cfquery name="getRecords" datasource="Test">
    Select USER_NUMBER, STATUS
    From USERS
</cfquery>  

<cfset myStruct = StructNew()>

<cfloop query="getRecords">
    <cfset myStruct[USER_NUMBER] = {status=STATUS}>
</cfloop>
```

Here is my .csv file converted to array:

```
<cffile action="read" file="#MyCSV#" variable="CsvFile">
<cfset myarray = ListToArray(CsvFile, chr(13))>
<cfset cnt = ArrayLen(myarray)>
```

In this part I used loops to compare records:

```
//array that holds user numbers
<cfset userNum = arrayNew(1)>
//array that holds status code
<cfset statusCode = arrayNew(1)>

<cfloop collection="#myStruct#" item="j">
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to=#(cnt)# step="1"> 
        <cfif len(trim(myarray[i])) GT 0>
            <cfset myrow = #replace(myarray[i],chr(10),'')#>
            <cfset myrow = ListToArray(myrow,",",true)>

            //compare if user numbers are the same
            <cfif #myrow[1]# EQ #j#>
                //compare if status code is different
                <cfif #myrow[23]# NEQ #myStruct[j].lunchst#>
                    //Store user number and status code that are different
                    //from csv file       
                    <cfset arrayAppend(userNum, "#myrow[1]#")>
                    <cfset arrayAppend(statusCode, "#myrow[23]#")>  
                </cfif> 
            </cfif> 
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>

//Here I converted both arrays to list
<cfset listUserNum = ArrayToList(userNum)>
<cfset listStatus = ArrayToList(statusCode)>
```

First i want to explain few things, I converted my arrays to lists because I was thinking that will be the best way to use in my UPDATE statements later but after I put some thoughts I realize that I can use list in WHERE clause but I can not use in UPDATE SET. What would be the best way to update those records. Second I have nested loops above that go through 14k records for each set of records that is not recommended and efficient. What would be other approach to do this and compare records? If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't you already [ask this same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300954/how-to-compare-values-from-struct-and-array-in-coldfusion)?

Comment: I asked one of the parts of this question.

Comment: Honestly, the *best* way to perform this kind of task using the database. Why are you not allowed to use temp tables (which are *temporary* after all)? It is a bit like the old expression "hiring someone to build a house, but telling them they cannot use any nails".  You should explain to the PTB that imposing these kinds of limitations will result in convoluted code that will not perform well. Especially as the volume grows. Just my $0.02 ..

Comment: Simply temporary tables are not allowed in PowerSchool. If I create any table I'm not able to delete that table later on.

Comment: (Edit) I do not know what "PowerSchool" is or what relation it has to [SQL Server temporary tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  However, it sounds very odd that you would not be able to DROP a *temporary* table, as they are dropped automatically when the session is closed anyway...

Comment: PowerSchool has a lot of limits and I'm not able to manipulate a lot of things around. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, knowing nothing about it, anything is possible, but ... what I am really asking if you are 100% certain you cannot use temp or staging tables, ie have you tried it? :) Because the alternative is a lot of looping and (potentially) 14K+ separate UPDATE statements. All of which adds up to an extremely inefficient process.

Comment: Yes I tried and I'm 100% sure that I can not use temp/staging tables. I would prefer to use them and that would be much easier and more efficient. Otherwise I have to use a lot of loops and that will not be efficient.

Comment: Why did you reject my suggestion from your other question?

Comment: @DanBracuk -  Can you elaborate on how you envision using it to identify differences, rather than matching records?

Comment: @DanBracuk I could not get that to work, I never used that before. I followed example on that link you provided but still did not help. If you can provide simple example I would appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: Show what you tried, describe what you hoped for, and then what happened.  By the way, when introduced to new concepts, you might find it useful to learn how they work with very simple examples.

Comment: @Leigh, something like, `where query1.something = query2.something and query1.somethingElse <> query2.somethingElse`.  Alternatively, one could use array functions on the query columns to do various things.  It depends on the specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

i just can advice to sort your lists before loops.
and rather continue inner loop than start from begin.